# Best search technique for mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have around 7 text boxes of which 3 are mandatory , I have one search table, I want to know what is the best logic to achieve the optimum search results.

Comment: Since 3 fields are mandatory , first ill use the usual technique select * from this table where name= "" , os="" ,"release"= if the count of rows is <0 then i plan to use the match / like query ..but dont know if this is the best technique also out of 7 parameters how do  i go about giving the match or like query ? this would consume a lot of time

Comment: Please edit your question with specific details of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend using full text search, it will search all the fields and ignore them if null, here is a decent guide on it http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/ and i would add filters that make it more than 2 characters and ignore an array of common words 
e.g put your search in a if statement like this

$ignorewords = array("the","and","their","there" ,"to","fix","make","add","then","if", "for", "then","or");

```
if ( (in_array(strtolower($value), $ignorewords) == false) && (strlen($value) > 2 ) )
```

use like "%{$value}%" to get things containing words or parts of words. the if statement checks if the search term ($value) is in the array, and if its not it will return false, the >2 restriction is to prevent someone typing "a" and getting everything with the letter a in back.

Comment: Note that the tutorial uses the dangerously out of date `mysql_query` function.